# Displaying list view Items when button is clicked

Tags: java, android, listview, button, android-edittext

I am creating a Tables app i.e. When a number is entered in editText and button is pressed, The list view will show the table of that certain number.
I tried this code but it keeps crashing.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView myListView;

    public final void generate(int timesTableNumber){
        ArrayList<String> timeTableContent= new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int j=1;j<=10;j++)
            timeTableContent.add(Integer.toString(j*timesTableNumber));

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,timeTableContent);

        myListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }

    public void table(View view)
    {
        EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        generate(Integer.parseInt(editText.toString()));
    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myListView=findViewById(R.id.myListView);

        generate(1);



    }
}
```

Comment: Post your stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add [**`getText()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText#getText()) .

```
 generate(Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString()));
```

Then use **`String.valueOf`**  instead of **`Integer.toString`**.

```
        for(int j=1;j<=10;j++)
        timeTableContent.add(String.valueOf(j*timesTableNumber));
```